# Identity Server is not working

Tags: identity-server

Good Day,
I have Sitecore 9.1.1 installed on Azure, I'm trying to log in but it keeps redirecting to an error page, when I checked the `identityServerAuthority` URL I found that it is not working (returning *HTTP ERROR 500*)

**Errors in log file**:

- `AuthenticationScheme: "idsrv" was not authenticated.`
- ````
    Action '"Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login 
       (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)"' with id   
       '"fdd94ee6-ac7d-427b-a0f4-7f0bbafd474e"' did not match the constraint
       '"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.HttpMethodActionConstraint"'   
       2019-12-30T00:00:54.8056717+00:00 [ERR] (Sitecore STS/RD2818786FC641)
       Connection id ""0HLS13DEQJHAB"", Request id   
       ""0HLS13DEQJHAB:00000001"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the 
       application. System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type   
       'Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.SecurityHeadersFilter' has been   
       registered.```
  ````

Comment: Which URL are you using to login to Sitecore? Generally there are 3 URLs when you install Sitecore in Azure. 1 for xconnect, 2 for Identity Server and the other for Sitecore itself. I think you are trying to login via the Identity Server one. Please cross check the url once

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Can I ask if you have a resolution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a long time since you have asked this question but I just went through the same situation and struggled to find the issue.

In my case, I found a "special character" in the NewClaims row (where you add the Sitecore Role that your user is going to receive)

[image]

And after I removed that "special character", everything worked fine as it supposed to.

Also, you can doublecheck in Notepad++ by enabling **View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters** and changing to Ansii **Enconding > ANSI**

[image]

I hope it also fix your issue and others whenever they search for the same problem.